# Dell XPS 13 9365 2-in-1 hangs on suspend Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, suspend

I bought a Dell XPS 9365 2-in-1 laptop over the weekend and immediately installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it (kernel 4.8.0-54-generic). I can't return from suspension meaning my computer hangs after either clicking suspend in the drop down menu or closing and reopening the lid. Pressing keys causes the keyboard back-light to turn on for a few seconds, and the front light will flash between white and orange for a while then stop. Sometimes I can hold the power button for ~5 seconds and it will finally wake up; however,  it is very inconsistent and the hold time is dangerously near the manual shutdown time.

Things I have tried, not in any particular order:

- sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade
- I upgraded to the most recent BIOS update
- This: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290
- This: https://askubuntu.com/questions/820955/blank-screen-after-resume-dell-m5510-ubuntu-16-04/829899#829899
- I corrected an issue where it was hanging on reset. I non-intrusively adjusted some settings and fixed it. I was having the suspension-hanging problems beforehand.
- I added use of one proprietary driver.

This post is very similar, and I have tried many of the same things to no avail: https://askubuntu.com/questions/875024/dell-xps-13-9365-2-in-1-wont-resume-after-suspend-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a site for programming questions - [tour] . For PC setup questions see SuperUser -  [su]

Comment: (If you can use Super User or Ask Ubuntu in the future, that would be great - this question and its answers may be deleted in the future, and that has the result of losing potentially valuable answers. Thanks!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a long time, but I finally figured out how to get a workable suspend-resume on the Dell XPS 9365 2-in-1. I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. I found most info [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192591).

I am not an expert, but here is my tentative explanation: there are several suspend modes, and the XPS 9365 only supports one of those, i.e., the suspend-to-idle or s2idle mode. However, the "deep" mode (suspend-to-ram) is the default.

Here's how to change that:

```
sudo su
echo s2idle > /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

Now the default suspend mode is s2idle, which works.

However, there are still some (minor) issues:

- The little led on the power button stays on (I think they are working on it)
- The machine can only be woken up by pressing the power button for about six seconds (a bit of a drag, but not the end of the world).
- Depending on your settings, pressing the power button will suspend the machine. If that is the case, the machine will immediately suspend again after being woken up.

In my case, I needed to change the following settings in Gnome:
Gnome Settings > Power > "When the power button is pressed": "Nothing"

Answer (score 5):

To make permanent the solution proposed by @user8211580 you should edit your grub config file with:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

edit the line containing

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

and make sure to include "mem_sleep_default=s2idle" like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=s2idle"
```

and then reload grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then make sure that you do not have any action linked to you power button. Next time you suspend your computer, you'll be able to wake it up by pressing your power button for 6 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

using what Denis Pitzalis and user8211580 said, I also upgraded the kernel to 4.13rc6 following somewhat broken directions at http://linuxg.net/install-kernel-4-13-on-ubuntu/

(directions  for 64bit show only installing the headers and not the actual image..)

anyway, suspend works now. I can close the lid and reopen later as well, all devices work and youtube resumes playing.